# Textarea string: limit to 1 empty line at a time

Tags: javascript, html, regex, angularjs, textarea

I have a `multivalue` `textarea` where each line represents one array value.

I want to remove empty lines if they exist when enter is pressed(im doing this through angular directive not on keypress). The expected result is that only one empty line can exist at the time.

I am trying to use `textareStringValue.replace(/\n{2,}/gm, '\n')`. But depending on the position of the new line and the text caret position the replace condition changes.

Can this be done with one `.replace(regExp)`?

```
app.directive('noTwolines', function () {

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '?ngModel',

      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
          if (!ngModel) return;
          ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (inputValue) {
              var digits = inputValue;
              var textarea= document.getElementById("textarea");
              var val = textarea.value;
              var caretPos = val.slice(0, textarea.selectionStart).length;
              console.log(inputValue.length);
              console.log(val.slice(0, textarea.selectionStart).length);

              if(caretPos === inputValue.length){
                console.log('enter from end');
                digits=  inputValue.replace(/\n{2,}/gm, '\n');
              }
              if(caretPos < inputValue.length && inputValue.indexOf('\n\n') != -1){
                digits=  inputValue.replace(/\n{3,}/gm, '\n');
              }

              ngModel.$setViewValue(digits);
              ngModel.$render();
              return digits;

          });
      }
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* this replace many empty line to one */     
textareStringValue.replace(/\s*\n/g,"\n")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it limits to create only a new line if the text caret is at position 0 of the string or end of it. It doesn't allow to create a new line in between values . As well if an empty line is created on position 0 of the string it allows you to create a new one at the end of the string without removing the former empty line. Same thing if the first empty line is created  at the end and then a new one is created at position 0.